# SQL Get Current Revision

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max

I have a table that records revisions for another table:

#### Revisions (r)

```
id     protocol     year     revision_created
----------------------------------------------------
100    PR00001      2015     7/29/2015 10:00:00 AM
101    PR00001      2015     8/29/2015 09:00:00 AM
102    PR00001      2016     2/12/2016 09:30:00 AM
250    PR00002      2016     3/10/2016 10:00:00 AM
251    PR00002      2016     3/10/2016 04:00:00 PM
252    PR00002      2016     8/31/2016 02:48:00 PM
```

I wanted to get the `id` of all the latest revision for each protocol for each year so in this case I wanted to get:

```
id     year    protocol
--------------------------
101    2015    PR00001
102    2016    PR00001
252    2016    PR00002
```

I have this query and it works but I feel like I shouldn't be using `MAX` on the `id` field but instead use it on the `revision_created` field - but if I do that then I won't be getting the `id`. Thoughts or suggestions?

```
SELECT MAX(r.id) AS id, r.year, r.protocol
FROM revision r
GROUP BY r.year, r.protocol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT id, year, protocol
FROM (  SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY protocol, year ORDER BY revision_created DESC) RN
        FROM revision) AS r
WHERE RN = 1
```

If you can't use `ROW_NUMBER`, you can join with the same table:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.year, r1.protocol
FROM revision r1
INNER JOIN (SELECT  protocol,
                    year,
                    MAX(revision_created) Max_Revision
            FROM revision
            GROUP BY protocol,
                     year) r2
    ON r1.protocol = r2.protocol
    AND r1.year = r2.year
    AND r1.revision_created = r2.Max_Revision
```

Comment: Ah, I should have added a requirement to my question. I could confirm that this works in PL/SQL but the third-party software that this query will be in only supports subqueries in the `select` clause. It doesn't even support `substr` and `replace` so I doubt it supports `over` or `partition by`.

Comment: for your updated answer PL/SQL gives me an error saying `missing keyword` and highlighting `AS r2`. - NEVERMIND I fixed it by removing the `AS` keywords on both `r1` and `r2`.

Comment: Yup taking the `AS` fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use an aggregation and `keep`:

```
SELECT r.protocol, r.year,
       MAX(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY r.revision_created DESC) as id
FROM revision r
GROUP BY r.year, r.protocol;
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially doing the same thing? Since I'm using `MAX` on the `id` instead of the timestamp? I'm just worried that the latest revision doesn't necessarily have the largest `id` in the group. I could also confirm that this works in PL/SQL but I have the same worry as with my original query.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . Not at all.  The `MAX()` is essentially ignored (a `MIN()` would do the same thing.  This gets the most recent `id` based on the `ORDER BY` clause.